# Why the data in my linked list will not be displayed? Java

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator

I am currently doing a book inventory system in linked list using Java GUI. I have to add book information into a Node in linked list and display it by implementing the iterator.

The exercise asked me to use my own Linked List and then implement the iterator to display it only.

I have done with my code and it shows no error. However, when I run the GUI and successfully add a book into the linked list then press the display button. It did not show the information I just added to the text area.

What in the code has done wrong?

This is my Node class:

```
public class Node 
{
    Data data;
    Node next;

    public Node()
    {
        next = null;
    }

    Node(Data data, Node next)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Object getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public Node getNext()
    {
        return next;   
    }

    public void setNext(Node next)
    {
        this.next=next;
   }
}
```

And this is my LinkedList class with the insertion and display method:

```
public class LinkedList
{
    Node node = new Node();
    static Data data;
    static Node head;

    public LinkedList()
    {
        head=null;
    }

    public static Node getHead()
    {
        return head;
    }

    public static void addNode(Data data, Node head)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node(data, head);
        Node previous = null;
        Node current = head;

        while(current != null && data.name.compareTo(current.data.name) >= 0){
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }

        if(previous == null){
            head = newNode;
        }else{
            previous.next = newNode;
        }
            newNode.next = current;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Book Information has been added to the inventory.");
    }
}

    public static String displayNode()
    {
        DisplayIterator i;
        Node current = head;
        String output = "";       
        while(DisplayIterator.hasNext())
        {
            output+= DisplayIterator.next();
            current=current.next;
        }      
        return output+"NULL";
    }
```

This is my data class which I used to store all the information into one Node:

```
public class Data {
    String name;
    String author;
    int isbn;
    int number;
    String genre;
    LinkedList list;
    static Node head = LinkedList.getHead();

    public Data(String name, String author, int isbn, int number, String genre)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.number = number;
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String toString(String name, String author, int isbn, int number, String genre)
    {
        return("Book Name: "+name+"\nAuthor: "+author+"\nISBN Number: "+isbn+"\nNumber of Copies: "+number+"\nGenre: "+genre+"\n");
    }
}

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public static Node getHead()
    {
        return head;
    }
```

And lastly this is my Iterator class:

```
public class DisplayIterator
{
    Data data;
    static Node current;

    DisplayIterator(Data data)
    {       
        this.data = data;
        current = data.getHead();   
    }

    public static boolean hasNext()
    {
        if(current != null){            
            return true;
        }       
        return false;       
    }

    public static Object next()
    {
        if(hasNext()){
        current = current.getNext();
        return current.getData().toString();            
    }       
        return null;        
    }

    public void remove()
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("It is read-only.");        
    }       
}
```

When I run the GUI, after the insertion, I click the button for display the linked list in the Text Area, however nothing appears there. Why?

This is my Display Button

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    LinkedList list;
    jTextArea1.setText(LinkedList.displayNode());
}
```

Please help telling me what is wrong in the code. Thank you.

Comment: You jumbleed together static and instance methods and variables all over your code. Try to get rid of statics. You don't need it here.

Comment: @YaroslavRudykh But if I get rid of static keyword some method are showing error to me.

Comment: Make sure all static keywords are gone, also the ones in method declarations...

Comment: @AdriaanKoster Okay I will try that, is that the problem why the information is not shown in the TextArea ?

Comment: It may be so. You program flow is ambiguous because of it.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your function jButton1ActionPerformed you create a new instance of LinkedList which contains no data. You don't call `
list.addNode() inside function or inside LinkedList constructor, so list contains no data. If you have any other instance of LinekdList that contains data that you want to display, you should use it instead of this instance inside the function.

Comment: The jButton1 is at different class with the Linked List so I have to create an instance there for call the displayNode() method from the class LinkedList.

Comment: You need to populate that instance with data somehow, or it will be always emptey. For test you could add some that to the instance, before you call displayNode();

Comment: Yes I do insert some data via Add Button in another class. Then I click the display button to display the data that I just insert. But it shows nothing.

Comment: You insert data to some other instance and not the the one that you create inside jButton1ActionPerformed.

If you would need just one instance of LinekdList you could change it to Singelton: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html
And you can access it from which ever class you want.

Comment: I see, okay I will try that. Thanks!